# class attribute is not recognized after changing html

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id=change>
<select class="select" name='' value='' >
        <option value="">------</option>
        <option value="">------</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I have changed inside the change div like this below.

```
$('#change').html("<select class='select' name='' value='' >\
        <option value=''>mango</option>\
        <option value=''>kinoko</option>\
    </select>");
```

I keep the class="select" attribute though,
it looks class="select" is invalid after changing html contents.

Is it the normal behaivor??

Comment: Why is it invalid? What's the problem you're having? Appears to work as I'd expect http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ne2o5tc0/

Comment: Wow. That HTML... Please, use `"` for ALL attributes and use `'` for Javascript strings. And how do you conclude that it is invalid?

Comment: Question doesn't make sense unless you are referring to events not being bound to the new html in which case you need to delegate the events handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your HTML as follows and see if you still have an issue:

```
<div id="change">
<select class="select" name="" value="" >
        <option value="">------</option>
        <option value="">------</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and your JS

```
$('#change').html('<select class="select" name="" value="" >\
        <option value="">mango</option>\
        <option value="">kinoko</option>\
    </select>');
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this. However class attribute not valid. As others mentioned my quetion is not good and don't hit the point. let me close this article for now , and I re-think and brush up the question. thanks for your help.